# How to prove that $(\Sigma a_i)^2\ge4\Sigma a_ia_{i+1}+2\Sigma a_ia_{i+n}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let $a_1$, $a_2$$\dots$, $a_{2n+1}$ be positive real numbers, where $n\ge4$. Prove that
> \[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1}a_i\right)^2\ge4\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1}a_ia_{i+1}+2\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1}a_ia_{i+n},\]
> where subscripts take modulo $2n+1$.

This is a refinement of the known inequality
\[(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_t)^2\ge4(a_1a_2+a_2a_3+\cdots+a_na_1).\]
I tried to let $a_{2n+1}=\min\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{2n+1}\}$, and $a_i=a_{2n+1}+b_i$, where $b_i\ge0$. By expanding, I got a quadratic of $a_{2n+1}$ of which the coefficient of $a_{2n+1}^2$ and $a_{2n+1}^1$ are non negative. Thus, it suffices to prove for $a_{2n+1}=0$, or to prove that the coefficient of $a_{2n+1}^0$ is also non-negative. For this part, perhaps the sum of squares method helps, for there still exists lots of posirife terms, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Maybe it is wrong... This is from an unofficial mock test.